# Rather dictatorial closing of my question

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I asked this question today:

[Does a vector assignment invalidate the `reserve`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24260717/does-a-vector-assignment-invalidate-the-reserve)

However it's been closed off **by a single user** (i.e. no voting process) as duplicate. That single user doesn't appear to be a diamond moderator. The problem with this is that the duplicate doesn't really contain answers that are satisfactory - specifically no reference to any C++ standard.

Now I need to go through the re-open process but this is asymmetrical in that it appears there is only one vote required for a duplicate close but several required for an open. I'm not sure that this question will ever reach re-open status. That doesn't seem right to me as this +5 question will now not be able to attract an answer. Of course I could re-ask a subtle variant of this question or even move to a different forum but those are both extreme and ineffective steps that I'd rather not pursue.

Comment: You may want to read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders/231212#231212

Comment: A single user *can* vote to reopen - if they also have a gold badge in one of the tags on the question.

Comment: Rats. My boss doesn't have a gold c++ badge. @Oded thanks for that link.

Comment: @Yogi, Johannes Schaub does quote the standard in [his comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663170/stdvector-capacity-after-copying#comment2680834_2663185): `It is guaranteed that no reallocation takes place during insertions that happen after a call to reserve() until the time when an insertion would make the size of the vector greater than the size specified in the most recent call to reserve()`. Does it not answer your question, especially coupled with the other answers?

Comment: Comments are fragile (they are often flagged and removed) and since they can't be downvoted and are not sufficiently peer-reviewed. As such they are the poor cousin of an answer. I'm therefore not confident it's correct. Yes, it would *appear* to be the case for `assign` but possibly not `operator=`.

Answer (score 15):

> The problem with this is that the duplicate doesn't really contain answers that are satisfactory - specifically no reference to any C++ standard.

**This is not a reason to avoid closing a duplicate question as a duplicate. Rather, it is a reason to improve or expand the answers to the existing question.**

If you can improve GMan's answer by adding a quotation from the language standard, you should do so. If you have some even more to offer, you should post a new answer of your own. If you cannot answer the question, but think it deserves a better answer with reference to the language standard, you should set a bounty on the question and choose an appropriate reason. Leave a custom message, too, mentioning the standard reference that you seek.

Anecdotally, I've seen a couple of experts who are regularly active answering C++ questions express disagreement with the closure process. Their argument has been that a new question shouldn't be marked as a duplicate of an existing question because the answers to that old question are bad, misleading, incomplete, or otherwise problematic.

I do not understand this objection. If there is a problem with the answers to the original question, *it should be remediated*. Just because the question is old doesn't mean we should allow it to fester. The primary audience served by this site is arguably those who arrive here via Google (or another search engine) looking for answers to a similar problem of their own. Which answers do you think they'll see first? The bad ones to an old, popular question, or the good one to a new question? We don't sort by date.

What boggles my mind is that, at least one of the times that I saw this, the dissenting individual re-opened the proposed duplicate and posted an *awesome* answer. Jeez, if you can do that, why not just post it on the original question where everyone can see it and benefit? Why have misleading information in Exhibit A and correct information in Exhibit B?

Comment: Quite often, the old question is in such a horrible state that it's simply better to start anew rather than trying to clean up all the confusing (and upvoted) answers on the old question. This is especially the case if editing the question into a better state would invalidate many of the answers.

Comment: @Mysticial, how exactly does leaving the previous "horrible state" alone help anyone, though? It leads directly into Cody Gray's point, the old (apparently broken) question is still a result in Google. Fix it, don't duplicate it.

Comment: You dupe the old messy question to the new canonical one. Or you can close or delete it. You tell me: How would you edit and broaden a question in a way that would invalidate all the answers? Make the edit and then flag all the answers as NAA? I don't think that's gonna settle well... This happens all the time if the answers only address the problem in the OP's 100-line extremely localized example - when it is better to replace that example with a 5-liner that best illustrates the problem or error condition that people will be googling for?

Comment: Questions like those Mystical describes shouldn't even have been answered in the first place. They should be downvoted, closed, and subsequently deleted. If that were happening like it should, there'd be no way to close future questions as duplicates of crap.

Comment: This doesn't give any recourse to the guy trying to get his question answered. If he knew the correct answer, he wouldn't have needed to ask it in the first place. It might not be relevant in this case, and it sounds like OP knows what's missing, but in a lot of cases this would prevent the asker from getting the info he needs. Let's be honest, an accepted answer on an old question is unlikely to get much scrutiny.